# Ubuntu, virtualenv, flask/bottle, and mod_wsgi not working, 500 internal server error

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, virtualenv, flask

I am having trouble with mod_wsgi and flask/bottle. At first I tried with bottle and then moved to flask but still cannot get it to work.

I know the problem is the app.wsgi file because I can get the hello world test to work ([hello_world_test_app](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#WSGI_Application_Script_File)).

**directory structure**

```
/path/to/ve/flask/
    hello.py
    app.wsgi
```

**hello.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**app.wsgi**

```
activate_this = '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from hello import app as application
```

**/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**
I commented out the daemon process b/c I just want to test if it works and don't need to use this right now, same for process group/application group.

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName dev-ubuntu

   # WSGIDaemonProcess hello user=user1 group=group1 threads=5
   WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/virtualenv/flask/app.wsgi

    <Directory /path/to/virtualenv/flask>
       # WSGIProcessGroup hello
       # WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**error log**

> [Fri Feb 17 14:43:20 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.32] ImportError: No module named hello

Comment: it's better to add your solution as an answer than editing your post

Comment: Rather than editing your question and adding *solved*, simply add your answer as an answer to your own question and accept it. Edit: Beaten to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

Does the apache user have read access to the '/path/to/virtualenv/flask' folder? Otherwise it can't read and import hello.